# ADAL 4 (experimental) behaves differently for Windows Desktop/Native and Windows Phone with B2C

Tags: oauth-2.0, windows-phone-8.1, adal, azure-ad-b2c

I want to create a Windows Phone 8.1 app with Azure AD B2C authentication.
As basis I used the [B2C Windows Desktop/Native Client sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-native-dotnet/).

The desktop app works pretty fine. In my WP8.1 adoption I run into the first problem at the point, where I want to acquire the token:

```
result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(new string[] { Globals.clientId },
                null, Globals.clientId, new Uri(Globals.redirectUri),
                platformParams, Globals.signInPolicy);
```

While I get a nice and shiny token for the desktop app, for the WP8.1 app (after coming back from the WebAuthenticationBroker) I only get a ...?code=...... response.

I'm not sure but for me it seems that the WP8.1 library works in a kind of [OIDC model](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc/) where the 1st call goes to the *authorize* and the 2nd to the *token* endpoint.

Picking up from there I tried to continue with the authorization code received with a

```
var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(authCode, new Uri(Globals.redirectUri),
                credApp, new string[] { "" }, Globals.signInPolicy );
```

but no matter how I try to pass in the *ClientCredential* or *ClientAssertion* I always end up with a plain **400 Bad request** (no more details are returned).

Someone please tell me where I'm wrong and/or point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone 8.1 uses a continuation model where WAB invokes the calling app back. Check out the sample at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-windowsphone-8.1/ to demo the flow or you can directly look at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-windowsphone-8.1/blob/master/TodoListClient/MainPage.xaml.cs

You need to implemented IWebAuthenticationContinuable interface on your page.
        }

```
    #region IWebAuthenticationContinuable implementation

    // This method is automatically invoked when the application is reactivated after an authentication interaction through WebAuthenticationBroker.        
    public async void ContinueWebAuthentication(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)
    {
        // pass the authentication interaction results to ADAL, which will conclude the token acquisition operation and invoke the callback specified in AcquireTokenAndContinue.
        await authContext.ContinueAcquireTokenAsync(args);
    }
    #endregion
```

*------------------------------------------------------------------*

UPDATE

I created a new windows phone app and referenced ADAL v4. I checked that continuation model does not apply to v4. It is only used by ADAL v2. Make sure that you are using adal-v4.
I still had to add the following code

```
 protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {

        if (args is IWebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs)
        {
            Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationHelper.SetWebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs(args as IWebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs);
        }

        base.OnActivated(args);
    }
```

This will resume the token acquisition process and return an access token

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of that and I implemented the continuation like I would do for a regular Azure AD. The point is that when coming back from the continuation, the AuthenticationResult is different from the Desktop app.

Comment: You are correct that it works in OIDC-ish way. This happens because desktop code controls the webview and is able to redeem the auth code to get you an access token in a single API call (acquireToken). In case of windows phone it is a 2 step approach because the WAB simply returns the auth code back to the developer, but it requires further processing to get the actual token, hence the continuation. But once you get the result from ContinueAcquireTokenAsync, it should contain an access token just like the desktop call.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense ... I'll try and give an update

Comment: I was not able to find the `ContinueAcquireTokenAsync(args)` implementation in the `Convergence-v4` and `Convergence-v4-RELEASE` branches of the [ADAL v4 repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet). As I understood I need to use the v4 in order to be able to pass in a B2C profile. `master` and `dev` branches to not seem to support profiles.

Comment: Suppose I would try to add support for the `ContinueAcquireTokenAsync` and `AcquireTokenInteractiveHandler(Authenticator authenticator, TokenCache tokenCache, IWebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)` to ADAL v4, I would not be able to succeed because `ContinuationData[]` is coming back with `null`

Comment: As I see it - correct me if I'm wrong - the ADAL v4 does not feed enough information into B2C `/authorize` endpoint or the endpoint just does not return any information which can go into the `ContinuationData[]`

Comment: Before working on an enhancement for ADAL v4 I wanted to check how the OAuth2 flow needs to be for Windows Phone 8.1. I [created a test app](https://github.com/KaiWalter/B2C-Windows81-OpenIDConnect-Test) with manual flows but I again only get **400 Bad request**

Comment: You need to get ADAL from here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/

Comment: @kanishk-panwar-msft: I started with the alpha library pulled from nuget - as supervised by dstrockis - see my [repo](https://github.com/KaiWalter/B2C-NativeClient-WindowsPhone8.1).  That's what brought up my initial question above: No `ContinueAcquireTokenAsync` and `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` does not do the trick.

Comment: onactivated() does not contain the code I pasted in update. Can you add that please?

Comment: I meant the call in your sample project.

Comment: @kanishk-panwar-msft: sorry, sorry, sorry ... I totally missed your update above. Inserting the `SetWebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs`in the apps `OnActivated` gives me the token. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I created a complete running sample Windows Phone 8.1 app with Azure AD B2C authentication [here...](https://github.com/KaiWalter/B2C-NativeClient-WindowsPhone8.1)

Findings (compared to a ADAL v2 Azure AD authentication):

- ContinuationManager is not needed - this is covered by `SetWebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs` in ADAL v4
- with this approach code continues execution directly after `AcquireTokenAsync`

Comment: Kai, thank you for posting an example for community.